# How do I use populate with callbacks?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

**`User model`**

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, reuired: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    posts:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Posts" }]
}, { timestamps: true })
```

**`Post model`**

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
}, { timestamps: true }
```

**`endpoint for getting all posts with all users information`**

```js
    listPostsWithUsers: (req, res, next) => {
        Post.find({}, (error, posts) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" })
            } else if (!posts) {
                return res.status(400).json({ msg: "sorry no posts" })
            } else if (posts) {
                return res.status(200).json({ posts })
            }
        })
    }
```

The output should be the returned posts with the user object so that I can identify which post the user has posted.

Now, my question is how do I apply **`populate()`** method in the above endpoint. Mostly all examples are with **`exec()`** function but I've seen no example with callbacks. It's kind of a syntax problem.

Thank you.

**`Update#1`**: The result I'm getting currently.

```js
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "_id": "5e65cce5ebddec0c5cc925ab",
            "title": "Neil's Post",
            "content": "post by neil.",
            "createdAt": "2020-03-09T04:58:13.900Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T04:58:13.900Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e65cd32ebddec0c5cc925ad",
            "title": "Slash's post",
            "content": "post by slash.",
            "createdAt": "2020-03-09T04:59:30.180Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T04:59:30.180Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e65f430a989612916636e8d",
            "title": "Jimmy's post",
            "content": "post by jimmy",
            "createdAt": "2020-03-09T07:45:52.664Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T07:45:52.664Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

**`Update#2`**

**`users`** collection.

```js
{
    "users": [
    {
        "posts": [],
        "_id": "5e65ccbeebddec0c5cc925aa",
        "username": "Neil",
        "email": "neily888@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$AHHRKuCX3nakMs8hdVj0DuwD5uL0/TJwkJyKZYR/TXPTrIo9f80IW",
        "createdAt": "2020-03-09T04:57:35.008Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T04:57:35.008Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "posts": [],
        "_id": "5e65cd0eebddec0c5cc925ac",
        "username": "Slash",
        "email": "slash938@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$QQX/CFJjmpGdBAEogQ4XO.1e1ZowuPCX7pJcHTUav7NfatGgp6sa6",
        "createdAt": "2020-03-09T04:58:54.520Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T04:58:54.520Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "posts": [],
        "_id": "5e65f408a989612916636e8c",
        "username": "Jimmy",
        "email": "jimmy787@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$/DjwWYIlNswgmYt3vo7hJeNupfBdFGe7p77uisYUViKv8IdhasDC.",
        "createdAt": "2020-03-09T07:45:12.293Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T07:45:12.293Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
    ]
}
```

**`Update#3`**:

**`usersController`**

```js
const User = require("../models/User")

module.exports = {

  createUser: (req, res) => {
    User.create(req.body, (err, createdUser) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      res.json({createdUser})
    })
  },


  listUsers: (res) => {
    User.find({}, (err, users) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      res.json({users})
    })
  },

  getUser: (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
        return res.json({user})
    })
  },

  updateUser: (req, res) => {

    const user = {
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    }

    User.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, user, { new: true }, (err, updatedUser) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        res.json({updatedUser})
    })
  },

  deleteUser: (req, res) => {
    User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (err, deleteduser) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
        return res.status(200).json({ user: deleteduser })
    })
  }
}
```

**`postsController`**

```js
const Post = require("../models/Post")

module.exports = {

  createPost: (req, res) => {

    const data = {
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
    }

    Post.create(data, (err, newPost) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
        return res.status(200).json({ newPost })
    })
  },


  listPosts: (res) => {
    Post.find({}, async (err, posts) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
        posts = await Post.populate(posts, {
          path: "user",
          model: "User"
        })
        return res.status(200).json({ posts })
    })
  },

  findPost: (req, res) => {
    Post.findById(req.params.id, (err, post) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
        return res.json({ post })
      }
    )
  },

  updatePost: (req, res) => {

    const post = {
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description
    }

    Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, post, { new: true },(err, updatedPost) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
          return res.status(200).json({ updatedPost })
    })
  },

  deletePost: (req, res) => {
    Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (err, deletedPost) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
        return res.status(200).json({ deletedPost })
    })
  }
}
```

**`Update#4`**

`router.get("/posts/:id", usersController.getUserPosts)` `

```js
    getUserPosts: (req, res) => {
        User.findById(req.params.id, async (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" })
            } else if (!user) {
                return res.status(400).json({ error: "No user" })
            } else if (user) {
                user = await User.populate("user", {
                  path: "posts",
                  model: "Post"
              })
            return res.status(200).json({ user })
         }
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use mongoose populate.

```
listPostsWithUsers : (req, res, next) => {
Post.find({}).populate('user').exec(function (err, data) {
 if (err) {
   console.log(err);
 } else {
     console.log(data);
   }
 })
}
```

[You can refer this official mongoose populate document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population)

You can even populate as many fields required by using populate as

```
populate([{ path: 'user' }, { path: 'book', select: { author: 1 } }])
```

with the help of select in populate, you can project the required fields (get only those fields from populated collection.)

## Edit 1

```
  createPost: (req, res) => {

const data = {
  title: req.body.title,
  description: req.body.description,
  user: req.user._id,
}

Post.create(data, (err, newPost) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
    return res.status(200).json({ newPost })
})
```

You will need to add user field in post while creating.
take user id from token or from query and you would be good to go.

## Edit 2

```
getUserPosts: (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.id).populate([{ path: 'posts' }])
     .exec(function (err, data) {
       if (err) {
        console.log(err);
       } else {
          console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

You are finding data in user module and you want to populate post data, so you just need to say which field you want to populate as you have already defined on field which model to refer by adding ref with that field in mongoose schema.

```
getUserPosts: (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.id, async (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" })
        } else if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "No user" })
        } else if (user) {
            user = await User.populate("posts")
        return res.status(200).json({ user })
     }
  })
}
```

This should also work for you.

Comment: Well, I did exactly that but not able to populate.

Comment: Can you please add your document as it is from mongoDB, so that we can help you figure out the way.

Comment: What document??

Comment: data in your database

Comment: I've updated my **`users`** collection. **`posts`** collection is there on **`Update#1`**.

Comment: Is in post collection document user field added, to populate user field in post you need to store actual user field with dataType as ObjectId('your userId') only then you will be able to populate data.

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you add some code in your answer?

Comment: You mean this?  `user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }`

Comment: I am asking what is stored in database.
To populate data initially your post data in db should look like this  

{
        "_id": ObjectId("5e65cd0eebddec0c5cc925ac"),
        "username": "Slash",
        "email": "slash938@gmail.com",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T04:58:54.520Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "user": ObjectID("5e47cd0eebddec0c5cc925fb")
}

Only if your data is stored in this way in db then only you will be able to use mongoose populate.

Comment: No, it's not stored like that. I've posted the routes above.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, you need to store user id in database and you will be good to go

Comment: Thanks for the help. One more help if you could, in **`Update4`**, I'm trying to get a particular user's posts. In postman, it's showing, **No user**.

Comment: Please have a look at edit 2 for your update 4 requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that after getting the posts as:

```
  listPostsWithUsers: (req, res, next) => {
        Post.find({}, async (error, posts) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" })
            } else if (!posts) {
                return res.status(400).json({ msg: "sorry no posts" })
            } else if (posts) {
                posts = await Post.populate(posts, {
                  path: 'user',
                  model: 'User'
                });
                return res.status(200).json({ posts })
            }
        })
    }
```